# update total with multiple list items by clicking on images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing, but I can't seem to get the total price to add properly. I can get each individual price, though.

Basically the idea is to click on a grayed out image, it generates a list(working) and it's suppose to give a price(which is does) and if you click on another image it should update the price, which would add to the previous price.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lolsen7/Acnx4/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="station-builder">
<a class="tools4" href="#"> <img id="keyboard" class="part" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Keyboard"/><span class="info">apple keyboard</span></a>
<a class="tools5" href="#"><img id="mouse2" class="part" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Mouse" ><span class="info">apple mouse</span></a
</div>

<div id="summaryTotal">
    <p>Get this system for as little as:</p>
</div>
<ul id="list">
    <li>2201L elo Touchscreen monitor</li>
    <li>Mac mini</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$ //JS FOR HARDWARE SECTION

$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".part").mouseover(function () {
            if (this.className !== 'part selected') {
                $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/100x100' + this.id + 'http://placehold.it/100x100');
            }
            $(this).mouseout(function () {
                if (this.className !== 'part selected') {
                    $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/100x100' + this.id + 'http://placehold.it/100x100');
                }
            });
        });

        var list = document.getElementById("list");
        var summaryTotal = document.getElementById("summaryTotal");
        var sum = 0;
        var total = 0;
        var finalTotal = 0;

        $(".part").click(function () {
            if (this.className == 'part') {
                $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/100x100' + this.id + 'http://placehold.it/100x100');
                console.log(this);



                if (this.id == 'keyboard') {
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    //li.setAttribute("alt","keyboard_li");
                    li.setAttribute("id", "keyboard_li");
                    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Keyboard'));
                    list.appendChild(li);


                    var keyboardPrice = "59";
                    sum = keyboardPrice * 1.2;
                    console.log(sum);
                    total = sum / 40;
                    console.log(total);

                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.setAttribute('id', 'keyboardTotal');
                    summaryTotal.appendChild(span);
                    $('#keyboardTotal').append(total);

                }
                if (this.id == 'mouse2') {
                    li = document.createElement("li");
                    li.setAttribute("id", "mouse_li");
                    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Mouse'));
                    list.appendChild(li);

                    var mousePrice = "59";
                    sum = mousePrice * 1.2;
                    console.log(sum);
                    total = sum / 40;
                    console.log(total);

                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.setAttribute('id', 'mouseTotal');
                    summaryTotal.appendChild(span);
                    $('#mouseTotal').append(total);

                }

            } else {
                $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/100x100' + this.id + 'http://placehold.it/100x100');
                console.log(this);

                if (this.id == "keyboard") {
                    $("#keyboard_li").remove();
                    $('#keyboardTotal').remove();
                }
                if (this.id == "mouse2") {
                    $("#mouse_li").remove();
                }

            }
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });

        total = $('#keyboardTotal') + $('#mouseTotal');


    });
```

Comment: I noticed that here is a `finaltotal` being initialized, why aren't you using it after that?

Comment: I removed it, after I posted this...my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make the following changes?

```
          var kbtotal = 0;//added
          var mstotal = 0;//added
          var keyboardPrice = 59;
          sum = keyboardPrice * 1.2;
          console.log(sum);
          kbtotal = sum / 40; // changed
          console.log(kbtotal); // changed

          var mousePrice = 59;
          sum = mousePrice * 1.2;
          console.log(sum);
          mstotal = sum / 40; // changed
          console.log(mstotal); // changed

          var finaltotal = parseFloat(kbtotal) + parseFloat(mstotal);
          $('#finaltotal').text(finaltotal); // added

<div id="summaryTotal">
    <p>Get this system for as little as: <div id="finaltotal"></div></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Both of these are still concatenating the item costs.

Comment: and now with the radix added?

Comment: Yea :( it still concatenates the items. Unless I need a "final" variable to add/update/remove item prices, but i figured I should still be able to use the variable "total".

Comment: Edited again... please review my changes.

Comment: it places a "0" for the first item and NaN for the second. However when console logged, it the prices show up correctly..

Comment: even with using total = parseFloat( parseFloat(kbtotal) + parseFloat(mstotal) ); it still concatenates the variables together. you can view the proper layout here: https://c9.io/laurenashley/lauren_17ootpik2

Comment: it adds it fine in the console, it's only concatenating in the viewport. How do I stop this?

Comment: Make changes as noted.